# How to set equal widths for UIViews using auto-layouts "Constraint with item format"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In my application I have inserted UIViews on view controller. My main requirement is that I want to set equal widths for both UIViews using auto-layouts "Constraint with item format".

For this I have written some code but I did not get equal widths. What did I do here wrong?

I want get result like below image (i.e need to set equal widths for both UIViews).

My code:

```
#import "ViewController8.h"

@interface ViewController8 ()
{
    UIView * myView1;
    UIView * myView2;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController8

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myView1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    myView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    myView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:myView1];

    myView2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    myView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    myView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:myView2];

    [self operation2];
}

-(void)operation2
{
    //Applying autolayouts for myview2

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:0
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:50]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:-10]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:-30]];

    //Applying autolayouts for myview1

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:10]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:0
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:50]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:myView2
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:-30]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:-30]];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Equal width constraint is not there in your posted code. Try adding this

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
  toItem:nil 
  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
  multiplier:1.0 
  constant:200]];


[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2
  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
  toItem:myView1
  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
  multiplier:1.0 
  constant:0]];
```

Comment: The explicit width constraint will lead to conflicting constraints because `view1` and `view2` are pinned horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to add the equal-width constraint

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:myView2
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];
```

You **must not** define the width of the two views explicitly using constraints because `view1` is pinned to the leading edge of the superview, `view2` is pinned to the trailing edge of the superview and the trailing edge of `view1` is pinned to the leading edge of `view2`. Hence, the constraint system is fully determined after adding the above equal-width constraint.

This is what adding the constraint will lead to:

[image: simulator screenshot with two equally sized views]

Answer (score 0):

Contemporary solution is using `NSLayoutAnchor`

```
myView1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView2.widthAnchor)
```

don't forget to activate this using `isActive = true`, or via `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()`.